# Android: How to passing a variable to the Parse.com cloud code

Tags: android, jquery, parameters, parse-platform

I am now working on CloudCode, and would like to retrieve the number of items in the Parse Database that is greater than certain criteria (i.e. an inputting parameter).

### Parse Cloud Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("query_num_greater_than_local", function(request, response) 
{
    var DB = Parse.Object.extend("Recording_db");
    var query= new Parse.Query(DB);
    query.greaterThan("Ref_int",1234);
    query.find(
    {
            success: function(results)
        {
                console.log("received " + results.length + " result(s)");
            response.success("done" + results.length);
            },
            error: function(error) 
        {
                console.log("error: " + error);
            }
    });
});
```

### Android code:

```
        ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("query_num_greater_than_local", new HashMap<String, Object>(), new FunctionCallback<String>() 
        {
            public void done(String result, ParseException e) 
            {
               if (e == null)  
               {
                   tv1.setText(""+result);      
               }
               else  
               {
                   tv1.setText("ParseException"+e);
               }
            }
        });
```

### Question:

While the above codes return a correct count of items greater than 1234, I would like to ask whether can **1234** be replaced as a parameter? i.e. query for a result based on an inputting variable query criteria, say become query.greaterThan("Ref_int", **2345**)?

If then, how could this variable inputting criteria be applied to the codes? Many thanks!

Comment: 1 ) The HashMap can contain String/Value pairs which is passed to the cloud code (as I recall via request.params) 2) Why are you using cloud code for this? The parse API has great query options directly in Android https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries

Comment: thanks for your advice. I have studied the link you have introduced and got it worked much easier!